# How do you find out if a control derives from a class

Tags: c#

I have a list of controls (_controlList) and from that list of controls I want to get the ones that derive from a given class. So I have code that looks like this.

```
List<Control> _controlList = new List<Control>();

public Control[] ControlsThatIsA(Type soughtType)
{
  List<Control> result = new List<Control>();
  foreach (Control control in _controlList)
  {
// This would have been nice but doesn't compile
//////////////
//  if (control.GetType() is soughtType)
    {
      result.Add(control);
    }
  }
return result.ToArray();
}
```

Any thoughts. I don't have to pass in the Type, it could be the string name of the class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I'd probably use generics:

```
public T[] ControlsOfType<T>() where T : Control
{
  List<T> result = new List<T>();
  foreach (Control control in _controlList)
  {
    if (control is T)
    {
      result.Add((T)control);
    }
  }
  return result.ToArray();
}
```

Or in .NET 3.5:

```
return _controlList.OfType<T>().ToArray();
```

If you need to use `Type`, then `IsAssignableFrom` is your friend, in particular:

```
if(soughtType.IsAssignableFrom(control.GetType())) {
   //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, that's a very nice way of solving that

Answer (score 1):

the C# is operator already does a type test (like the Vb TypeOf operator), so it expects something like
if (control is MyNamespace.MyControl)
this is fine if you know the type you are looking for at compile time, but no good for your situation.
Also, if your test was changed to do a reference equals test (sorry, I'm a VB programmer really, the VB operator would be IS but I don't know the c# one) then your test would only return true if the control was the type tested for, not it it was inherited from the soughtType.
Try
control.GetType().IsSubClassOf(soughtType)

Note that IsSubClassOf won't return true if control is one of soughtType, but your question did ask to find only controls that inherited from soughtType.

Comment: Whoops, that was intended to be an edit of my previous answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comments pTG I didn't know about .IsSubClassOf.

Answer (score -1):

```
if( control is soughtType )
{
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't compile it went very closely with what i had. This complies for you?

Comment: Why would it never return true ?  If 'soughtType' is the type that you're looking for, this will definitly return true.
And it will compile as well.
soughtType should not be a string or whathever, it should really be the name of the type.

Comment: I think it was my mis-understanding of the is operator, the -1 stands becuase it doesn't compile though.  soughtType is an instance of Type in the OP's question.